# Why Spring cloud config server is not properly doing the request to Vault as it does to Git?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

This is our rough **setup**(application, config-server, vault, git), this is what we want to **achieve** (proxy vault/git through config-server) and this is **our problem** (we can only get requests one of the config-server backends and not both at the same time)

We used token (X-Config-Token) based Authentication to fetch config from Git and Vault when ever requesting the configurations through config server.

We have tried with following configuration setup in Config server.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault , git
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        accept-empty: false
        git:
          order: 2
          uri: https://gitlab/project/config-sample-nonprod/{profile}}
          deleteUntrackedBranches: true
          tryMasterBranch: false
        vault:
          order: 1
          host: vault-dev-project.com
          backend: kv/project/sample-platform-sandbox/
          default-key: sample-collector/mmg-sample
          port: 443
          scheme: https
          authentication: TOKEN
          kv-version: 2
          token: xxxxxewdsdjbcxxxxxxxx
        failOnCompositeError: false
```

We are testing our API requests using CURL to see the configuration of client application coming through config server from different backend as below:

**Git as backend**

Applications should get its configuration from the config server using the following URL pattern:

`https://<config-service>/<name>/<repo>/<branch or tag>`

Example as below:

`curl -X GET https://sample-config-service-dev/sample-collector/mmg-sample/develop -H X-Config-Token:0cd3253`

We are getting the configuration as response from our Gitlab

**Vault as backend**

`curl -X GET https://config-service-dev.com/sample-collector/mmg-sample,dev -H X-Config-Token:0cd3253`

Response:

`{"name":"sample-collector","profiles":["mmg-sample,dev"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"vault:sample-collector/mmg-sample,dev","source":{"env":"development","project":"sample","user":"test1"}}]}`

When we send the request to Vault as config-service-dev.com/sample-collector/mmg-sample,dev to get the secrets related to development as above, we are getting the desired results.

But when we are trying to fetch the results for below request from Vault,

`curl -X GET https://config-service-dev.com/sample-collector/mmg-sample/develop -H X-Config-Token:0cd3253`

It throws me an error as below

`{"timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:24","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/sample-collector/mmg-sample/develop"}`

[Above request Vault image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhdam.png)

Logs from Config server:

```
{"@timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:23.947Z","log.level":"DEBUG","message":"Matching [/actuator/**] against [/sample-collector/mmg-sample/develop]...",,"process.thread.name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","log.logger":"com.mm.mspconfigservice.SecurityConfiguration","transaction.id":"80fa2d228749ba6f","trace.id":"d63fcb6f26f57454b72a58ec3e81fabc"}

{"@timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:24.007Z","log.level": "INFO","message":"URI 'https://sample.com/g/m/config-mcp-nonprod/mmg-sample': following HTTP redirect #0 https://sample.com/g/m/config-mcp-nonprod/mmg-sample/ -> https://sample.com/g/m/config-mcp-nonprod/mmg-sample.git/",,"process.thread.name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","log.logger":"org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp","transaction.id":"80fa2d228749ba6f","trace.id":"d63fcb6f26f57454b72a58ec3e81fabc"}

{"@timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:24.145Z","log.level": "WARN","message":"**Error occured cloning to base directory**.",,"process.thread.name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","log.logger":"org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository","transaction.id":"80fa2d228749ba6f","trace.id":"d63fcb6f26f57454b72a58ec3e81fabc","error.type":"org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException","error.message":"Invalid remote: origin","error.stack_trace":[

"org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin",

"Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: https://sample.com/g/m/config-mcp-nonprod/mmg-sample: https://sample.com/g/m/config-mcp-nonprod/mmg-sample.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: Not Found",

{"@timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:24.147Z","log.level": "INFO","message":"**Error adding environment** for org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository@29a4dec2",,"process.thread.name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","log.logger":"org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.SearchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository","transaction.id":"80fa2d228749ba6f","trace.id":"d63fcb6f26f57454b72a58ec3e81fabc"}

{"@timestamp":"2024-02-04T15:37:24.147Z","log.level": "WARN","message":"Error getting the Environment with name=sample-collector profiles=mmg-sample label=develop includeOrigin=false",,"process.thread.name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","log.logger":"org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController","transaction.id":"80fa2d228749ba6f","trace.id":"d63fcb6f26f57454b72a58ec3e81fabc","error.type":"org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentNotFoundException",**"error.message":"Profile Not found",**"error.stack_trace":[

"org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentNotFoundException: Profile Not found",
```

Even though, we gave in the API request to fetch the details from Vault secrets, it is first redirecting to Git and throwing an error **without checking** in **Vault**.